# My main thread stops execution of code randomly after some time?

Tags: c++, curl, jsoncpp

Kinda hard to explain this question but I will try!

So I have made a bot that plays a game for me. It happens in a while loop, and it starts the game for me, plays it, and exits to start a new.
However sometimes it just stops the execution of my code, when it is supposed to keep doing that loop, to keep playing the game for me.

This time it stopped the execution with this output from the console and just doesn't execute more, even though its supposed to!:

```
State:
curl_easy_perform() failed: Timeout was reached
58107
hY2mCQUpcGg3iTDDzgE3kQ
curl_easy_perform() failed: Timeout was reached
58107
hY2mCQUpcGg3iTDDzgE3kQ
curl_easy_perform() failed: 2
Still in champselect or looking for match!
58107
hY2mCQUpcGg3iTDDzgE3kQ
Parsed!:
null

State:
```

and that is in this part of my code:

```
lobbyCreated = curl_create_lobby();
        if (lobbyCreated)
        {
            cout << "Phase 1 create!" << endl;
            Sleep(5000);
            curl_find_match();
            Sleep(500);
            if (curl_find_match)
            {
                curl_ready_check();
            }
        
        }
```

The code it stopped at, makes an API request to create a game lobby and if that is succeeded it starts the game, and accepts the game once a game is ready.

I just really dont know why it would stop the execution of the program, all I know is that if it has waited for some time and not found a game, it seems to happen. If everything goes well, and it is in the game fast, it doesn't seem to stop the execution of the code.

The curl and jsoncpp functions, it always seems to stop the execution at, after a random number of games has been played:

```
bool curl_create_lobby() {

    std::string output = exec("wmic PROCESS WHERE name='LeagueClientUx.exe' GET commandline"); // CMD Exec.

    Sleep(2000);

    regex find_port("([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])");
    regex find_token("remoting-auth-token=([\\w-]+)");


    string port = PrintMatch(output, find_port);                        // Regex find desired information we need.
    string authToken = PrintMatch(output, find_token);

    string EncodedAuth = Encoder.Encode("riot:" + authToken);                 // Encode the auth token to base64 riot:"authtoken" --> base64
    string Authorization = "Authorization: Basic " + EncodedAuth;
    const char* charAuthorization = Authorization.c_str();                  // Cast the base64 auth token into a char so we can use it as parameter with libcurl.

    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");                          // Define the required headers.
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept-Charset: utf-8");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, charAuthorization);

    /*                                                                                         
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                 CODE ABOVE MUST BE REUSED FOR EACH API CALL, STORE IT IN GLOBAL SCOPE WHEN YOU WANNA USE UR TIME!*/   
    // API CALL BELOW FOR THIS CALL ONLY!

    string urlRequest_create_lobby = "https://127.0.0.1:" + port + "/lol-lobby/v2/lobby";
    const char* charUrlRequest_create_lobby = urlRequest_create_lobby.c_str();                  // Cast the url into a char so we can use it as parameter with libcurl.

    CURL* curl_create_lobby;
    CURLcode res_create_lobby;
    
    
    
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_create_lobby = curl_easy_init();



    curl_easy_setopt(curl_create_lobby, CURLOPT_URL, charUrlRequest_create_lobby);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_create_lobby, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_create_lobby, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
   
    
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_create_lobby, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\
     \"customGameLobby\": {\
     \"configuration\": {\
      \"gameMode\": \"CLASSIC\", \"gameMutator\": \"\", \"gameServerRegion\": \"\", \
    \"mapId\": 11, \
    \"mutators\": {\"id\": 1}, \"spectatorPolicy\": \"AllAllowed\", \"teamSize\": 5\
    }\
    },\
    \"queueId\": 830,\
    \"isCustom\": false\
    }");

    res_create_lobby = curl_easy_perform(curl_create_lobby);
    if (res_create_lobby != CURLE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
        curl_easy_strerror(res_create_lobby));
        return false;
       
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

    

}




bool curl_find_match() {

   

    std::string output = exec("wmic PROCESS WHERE name='LeagueClientUx.exe' GET commandline"); // CMD Exec.

    Sleep(2000);

    regex find_port("([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])");
    regex find_token("remoting-auth-token=([\\w-]+)");


    string port = PrintMatch(output, find_port);                        // Regex find desired information we need.
    string authToken = PrintMatch(output, find_token);

    string EncodedAuth = Encoder.Encode("riot:" + authToken);                 // Encode the auth token to base64 riot:"authtoken" --> base64
    string Authorization = "Authorization: Basic " + EncodedAuth;
    const char* charAuthorization = Authorization.c_str();                  // Cast the base64 auth token into a char so we can use it as parameter with libcurl.

    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");                          // Define the required headers.
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept-Charset: utf-8");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, charAuthorization);

    /*
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                 CODE ABOVE MUST BE REUSED FOR EACH API CALL, STORE IT IN GLOBAL SCOPE WHEN YOU WANNA USE UR TIME!*/
  

    string urlRequest_find_match = "https://127.0.0.1:" + port + "/lol-lobby/v2/lobby/matchmaking/search";
    const char* charUrlRequest_find_match = urlRequest_find_match.c_str();

    CURL* curl_find_match;
    CURLcode res_find_match;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_find_match = curl_easy_init();


    curl_easy_setopt(curl_find_match, CURLOPT_URL, charUrlRequest_find_match);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_find_match, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_find_match, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_find_match, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{}");
    
    res_find_match = curl_easy_perform(curl_find_match);
    if (res_find_match != CURLE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %S \n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res_find_match));
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

void curl_ready_check() {

    std::string output = exec("wmic PROCESS WHERE name='LeagueClientUx.exe' GET commandline"); // CMD Exec.

    Sleep(2000);

    regex find_port("([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])");
    regex find_token("remoting-auth-token=([\\w-]+)");


    string port = PrintMatch(output, find_port);                        // Regex find desired information we need.
    string authToken = PrintMatch(output, find_token);

    string EncodedAuth = Encoder.Encode("riot:" + authToken);                 // Encode the auth token to base64 riot:"authtoken" --> base64
    string Authorization = "Authorization: Basic " + EncodedAuth;
    const char* charAuthorization = Authorization.c_str();                  // Cast the base64 auth token into a char so we can use it as parameter with libcurl.

    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");                          // Define the required headers.
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept-Charset: utf-8");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, charAuthorization);

    /*
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                 CODE ABOVE MUST BE REUSED FOR EACH API CALL, STORE IT IN GLOBAL SCOPE WHEN YOU WANNA USE UR TIME!*/

    CURL* curl_ready_check;
    CURLcode res_ready_check;
    
    unique_ptr<string> httpData(new string());                                                  // Store the response from the GET request.
    string UrlRequest_ready_check = "https://127.0.0.1:" + port + "/lol-matchmaking/v1/ready-check"; // Is there a match??
    string UrlRequest_ready_check_accept = "https://127.0.0.1:" + port + "/lol-matchmaking/v1/ready-check/accept"; // Accept match
    const char* charUrlRequest_ready_check_accept = UrlRequest_ready_check_accept.c_str(); // Accept Match
    const char* charUrlRequest_ready_check = UrlRequest_ready_check.c_str();

    curl_ready_check = curl_easy_init();
    
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_ready_check, CURLOPT_URL, charUrlRequest_ready_check);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_ready_check, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_StdString);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_ready_check, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_ready_check, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_ready_check, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_ready_check, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, httpData.get());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_ready_check, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);

    curl_easy_perform(curl_ready_check);

    // Parse the response.

    Json::Value jsonData;
    Json::Reader jsonReader;

    if (jsonReader.parse(*httpData, jsonData));
    {
        cout << "Parsed!: " << endl;
        cout << jsonData.toStyledString() << endl;

        const string current_ready_state(jsonData["state"].asString());

        cout << "State: " << current_ready_state << endl;

        if (current_ready_state != "InProgress")
        {
            curl_easy_perform(curl_ready_check);
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        CURL* curl_ready_check_accept;
        CURLcode res_ready_check_accept;

        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
        curl_ready_check_accept = curl_easy_init();

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_ready_check_accept, CURLOPT_URL, charUrlRequest_ready_check_accept);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_ready_check_accept, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_ready_check_accept, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_ready_check_accept, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{}");

        res_ready_check_accept = curl_easy_perform(curl_ready_check_accept);
        if (res_ready_check_accept != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res_ready_check_accept));
        }
        if (current_ready_state == "Not attached to a matchmaking queue.")
        {

            curl_create_lobby();
            Sleep(2000);
            curl_find_match();
            Sleep(300);
            void curl_ready_check();
            void curl_ready_check_accept();
        }
    }
  
   
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you take a read of [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) as debugging is a rather important part programming

Comment: I know it is and I have debugged. And I find no reason to why it should stop at a random..

Comment: Why you use a function as a boolean? `curl_find_match(); Sleep(500); if (curl_find_match)`. There is not enough code to know why it fails.

Comment: Im just using it as a bool to return if it successfully did the curl request, if not it does it again. The function simply makes the post request to the API to create the lobby and start it. That it failed this time is not why the execution stops I'm sure. Most times it stops during successful api requests.

Comment: @Manuel means it should be `curl_find_match()`, with empty parentheses in the end. Otherwise you're referring to the function's address, not calling the function. The `if` just checks if the function is at a positive address, which is always true.

Comment: It's pretty hard to say anything more withouyt a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Lordi1000 as Yosef Meller says, using the function as a boolean value is a mistake.

Comment: @YosefMeller I know what that if does, but I ask why OP is using it like that.

Comment: Yes, I was explaining to the OP, as evidenced by the lack of coma after your name.

Comment: Alright thanks for the input people, appreciate it! I'll edit my main post with some more code, It's always when I do the API requests it ends up stopping at a random time!